# Mapbox SearchUI

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-ios

Trying Mapbox SearchUI. 
When searching, I've noticed suggestions and results are only when the string I'm searching for is part of a name of a place...matching street names and addresses are not returned.
The documentation is not very detailed, since default did not provided the required results I've tried to use SearchOptions, it has a property named filterTypes.
It's of SearchQueryType type, tried to set it with [.address, .place, .locality, .street] and got an error..
so I removed the 'street' value and it started working again with no errors, but with no street/address results only names of places.
Also tried with and without languages option..
What am I missing?

```
        var options = SearchOptions()
        
        options.languages = ["en","he"]
        
       // options.fuzzyMatch = true
        //country, region, postcode, district, place, locality, neighborhood, address, poi, street.
        options.filterTypes = [.address, .place, .locality]
        options.origin = mapView.userLocation.coordinate
```

````
pod 'MapboxCoreNavigation', :git => 'https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios.git', :tag => 'v2.0.0-beta.20'

pod 'MapboxNavigation', :git => 'https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios.git', :tag => 'v2.0.0-beta.20'```
````

Answer (score 0):

The official answer I've got from Mapbox team:

> Thanks for your feedback. It looks like that .street filter option is unsupported for the latest public API version. Please, ignore this option until public SDK release. However, .address filter type includes .street behaviour in general.
> You implemented SearchEngine properly but, unfortunately, we have limited search coverage in Israel at the moment and that's the real reason why you don't see any valid search results.

[full discussion @ github](https://github.com/mapbox/search-ios-examples/issues/5)